# Can't type in commands after reattching to a screen session

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

Using CentOS 5, I have a screen session running and I often reattach to it after a day or two with the usual:

```
screen -r <sockname>
```

The session reattaches fine, and runs fine (I can see output from ongoing processes happening in the background) but I can't enter in any commands... Does anyone have any tips for getting screen sessions to start accepting your commands again?

Note that I can enter C- commands successfully, I.E. C-d detaches the session, C-[ enters copy mode - k,l then scroll through the buffer. I simply can't enter in any system commands, like ps etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to detach any existing sessions in order to take the write lock for the session. For example, `screen -d -r`

Comment: Thanks Tom, will give that syntax a try next time it occurs and update the question status.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367669/the-gnu-screen-is-unresponsive-seems-blocked), it may be that you have hit `ctrl` + `a` `s`, which blocks scrolling, making it appear than anything you type is not entered.

Hit `ctrl` + `a` + `q` to unblock scrolling.

N.b. `ctrl` + `a` is the escape sequence of course, so if you've changed that, use whatever you set.

All credit to user wkl on Stack Overflow. I'm just posting here for anyone who finds this question first.